# swift how to adopt to NSURLSessionDownloadDelegate protocol

Tags: ios, swift, nsurlsession, nsurlsessiondownloadtask

I want to create a class that adopts to `NSURLSessionDownloadDelegate` protocol

what i did is:

```
class imageDelegate: NSURLSessionDownloadDelegate  {
}
```

that is easy and it is fine. but i wanted to add one of it s method. i did this:

```
class imageDelegate: NSURLSessionDownloadDelegate  {
     @objc func URLSession(session: NSURLSession, downloadTask: NSURLSessionDownloadTask, didFinishDownloadingToURL location: NSURL) {
        print("asdfasf")
    }
}
```

then i got error:

```
 Type 'imageDelegate' does not conform to protocol 'NSObjectProtocol'
```

any idea how to solve that please?

Comment: It is Swift convention to name your classes starting with an uppercase letter

Comment: @LeoDabus okay i'll change it. do you knwo a solution to my problem?

Answer (score 0):

I usually use the calls that take completion blocks, so I'm not that familiar with using an `NSURLSessionDownloadDelegate'.

The error you're getting says you need to conform to the NSObject protocol, which tells me you need to make your class a subclass of NSObject. That will get you past the current error you're getting.

Take a look at the docs for the NSURLSessionDownloadDelegate protocol. It looks like there are 3 methods in the protocol.

EDIT: Looking at the header for the protocol, only `thedidFinishDownloadingToURL` method is required. The other 2 are optional.

However, If you take a look at the docs, they say:

> The NSURLSessionDownloadDelegate protocol defines delegate methods
>   that you should implement when using NSURLSession download tasks. In
>   addition to these methods, be sure to implement the methods in the
>   NSURLSessionTaskDelegate and NSURLSessionDelegate protocols to handle
>   events common to all task types and session-level events,
>   respectively.

So you also need to implement the methods from the `NSURLSessionTaskDelegate` and `NSURLSessionDelegate` protocols.